# How to set Minimum TLS version in azure cosmos

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb

Terraform allows for setting the minimal TLS version in some of the azure resources, [for example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#minimum_tls_version):

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "myApp" {
  site_config {
    ...
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  }
  ...
```

I could not find a way to set it for a [cosmosdb_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account) resource with terraform configurations. Is there a way?

I can see the config exists in the azure portal:
[image]

Comment: looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21295) in terraform for this...

Comment: Currently it is possible with the Azure API only. Did you try using `azapi_update_resource` to update the TLS version of a cosmos account. @The Fabio

Comment: I prefer to set it manually than using another provider at this stage... Creating a cosmos account is not something that happens all the time

Comment: Got it. And one more alternative you can try is using PowerShell. You can create an Azure Policy to enforce TLS version settings for Cosmos DB accounts.

Comment: Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) to use `azapi_resource` resource. I can provide you a clear repro if this works for you. @The Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21295) issue, currently setting `TLS_version` is not supported with the `azurerm_cosmosdb_account`. To enable it, you can use [`azapi_resource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) or [`azapi_update_resource`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs/resources/azapi_update_resource) if the resource is already existed.

*I tried below code to achieve your requirement and the deployment was successful as shown.*

```bash
terraform {
 required_providers {
   azapi = {
     source = "Azure/azapi"
   }
 }
}

provider "azapi" {
}

provider "azurerm"{
 features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
 name     = "DefaultResourceGroup-EUS"
}

data "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
 name                = "newcb"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "azurerm_cosmosdb_account_tls_update" {
 type        = "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-03-15"
 resource_id = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db.id
 body = jsonencode({
   properties = {
     minimalTlsVersion = "Tls12"
   }
 })
}
```

Previously my cosmos dB account had  `minimum_tls_version` set to `TLS1.1`

[image]

After the successful deployment with the above given code, it got upgraded to the `TLS 1.2` as shown.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, as a workaround, you can use an Azure Policy to set TLS version settings for Cosmos DB accounts. To achieve it, create a policy that requires Cosmos DB accounts to use a specified TLS version, then attach it to your resource group.

Once you have defined the policy with a set of rules and actions, assign it using [`New-AzPolicyAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-10.4.1) along with the `scope` parameter as cosmos dB scope.

```
$policy=New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name 'xxx' -Policy <policypath>
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'xxxx' -PolicyDefinition  $Policy -Scope "cosmosdb account resourceID"
```

*Note:* Create a policy rule as per your requirements.

Comment: I will keep using the portal until the cosmosdb_account resource is updatred in terraform... I will mark this as the solution as I can confirm it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is now covered since the azurerm provider version 3.94.0 (February 29, 2024)
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3940-february-29-2024

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account#minimal_tls_version

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.